# Recycler View not Showing the Youtube Videos

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create an app that loads youtube videos, but then when I go to run the app it doesn't show up, all I get is a blank screen that I can scroll on. I don't know why it isn't showing up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included the 2 xml files, and the java classes that I am using for this.

Videos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/video_view">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Videos_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/videoWebView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </WebView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

YoutubeVideos.class

```
public class YoutubeVideos {
    String videoUrl;

    public YoutubeVideos() {

    }

    public YoutubeVideos(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

}
```

VideoAdapter.class

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder>{

    List<YoutubeVideos> youtubeVideoList;

    public VideoAdapter() {

    }

    public VideoAdapter(List<YoutubeVideos> youtubeVideoList) {
        this.youtubeVideoList = youtubeVideoList;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_view, parent, false);
        return new VideoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.videoWeb.loadData(youtubeVideoList.get(position).getVideoUrl(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return youtubeVideoList.size();

    }

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        WebView videoWeb;
        public VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            videoWeb = (WebView) (itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoWebView));
            videoWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            videoWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        }
    }

}
```

VideoActivity.class

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Vector<YoutubeVideos> youtubeVideos = new Vector<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.videos);
        //this leaves the keyboard hidden on load
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_videos); // for set actionbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fX173Ppe4bY\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShmBRvnnPNs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SmA6_q0gP0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FfmX36BY4w\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7vsULnwvQA\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3mV1nSMh8E\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Baz0cbF2FeU\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Olc4U_UpnSE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq_2BZXORts\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PW7Kyjx5w74\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnoizmhXCxM\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));
        youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" aro=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0p_lEix7PKM\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"));

        VideoAdapter videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(youtubeVideos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have declared uses Internet permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

2. Your Youtbe frame script isn't correct, update it. I have made some corrections in your code that might be helpful to you.

YoutubeVideos.class

```
public class YoutubeVideos {
    String url;

    public YoutubeVideos() {

    }

    public YoutubeVideos(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Youtube Frame to be attached into a Webview.
     * @description This helper function will allow you to generate web url with predefined settings. You can modify the height, width and other parameters.
     */
    public String getFrame(){
        return "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\""+ url +"\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    }

}
```

VideoAdapter.class

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Load frame of video in web view.
        holder.videoWeb.loadData(youtubeVideoList.get(position).getFrame(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
```

finally, update your You activity to place video link only.

VideoActivity.class

```
// Pass only the URL of video
youtubeVideos.add(new YoutubeVideos("https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8"));
```